# Spring Boot object was not transferred completely to browser

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, postman, request-mapping

I transferred an object form Spring Boot Server with ResponseEntity to the browser.

```
public class Document
{
    @Id
    private long documentId;
    private String documentNumber;
    private int index;
    private String checkSum;
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;
    private User createdBy;
    private OffsetDateTime modifiedAt;
    private User modifiedBy;
    private String placeholder;
    private boolean indexing;
    private String changeLog;
    ... // Getter and Setter
}
```

But if i send the same object a few minutes later to browser some fields are missing.
The variable *placeholder*, *changeLog* and *indexing* are missing, if i send the same request twice to server.

```
@PermitAll
@GetMapping("/test.do")
public ResponseEntity<Object> test()
{
    Document document = new Document();
    document.setDocumentId(1);
    document.setDocumentNumber("Test");
    document.setIndex(2);
    // ...
    document.setPlaceholder("Hello");
    document.setIndexing(true);
    document.setChangeLog("This is the first test");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(document, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I test the request with postman.

```
http://localhost/test.do
Response:
{
    "documentId": 1,
    "documentNumber": "Test",
    "index": 2,
    "checkSum": null,
    "createdAt": null,
    "createdBy": null,
    "modifiedAt": null,
    "modifiedBy": null,
    "placeholder": "Hello",
    "indexing": true,
    "changeLog": "This is the first test"
}
```

After second call:

```
http://localhost/test.do
Response:
{
    "documentId": 1,
    "documentNumber": "Test",
    "index": 2,
    "checkSum": null,
    "createdAt": null,
    "createdBy": null,
    "modifiedAt": null,
    "modifiedBy": null
}
```

Has anyone an idea, what am I doing wrong in this case.
I have upgrade the spring boot frame version to 2.4.2.

Comment: Could you check if the response status code is 30x by any chance?

Comment: In every case i got the response status code 200.